# Where do i download patch for magento2 version

Tags: patches, magento-2.1.9, download

I see most recent patch realeased **MAGENTO 2.2.3**, **2.1.12** and **2.0.18 SECURITY UPDATE**

I want to download for my Magento version 2.1.9. How and where do I download the patch file?

Comment: check [this link](https://magento.com/security/patches/magento-223-2112-and-2018-security-update)

Answer (score 1):

You can download them from official Magento website:

https://magento.com/tech-resources/download

Some more information:

https://magento.com/security/patches/magento-223-2112-and-2018-security-update

Answer (score 1):

Its better to go for version upgrade with the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ssh access to your magento instalation, you can update magento using composer:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.3 --no-update
```

And then run:

```
composer update --optimize-autoloader
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:stati-content:deploy
```

**Note:** Make a backup before preceed. All comands must be executed on magento root folder.