# How to secure my website magento 2

Tags: magento2, security

I want to secure my website from script injection and other Security failures so is there patch or somthing that i have to do or upload to do so.

Also i want advice from you concerning sécurity magento 2.

And how to change the **url** of `backend from /admin` to `/somthing/admin`.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think you should check your site report [here](https://magento.com/security) and [here](https://www.magereport.com/), do action accordingly.

Comment: go to app/etc/env.php and open it search **'frontName' => 'admin'** and replace **admin** to what you want

Comment: yes changing the **frontName => admin** to **something/admin** in env.php is the right approch. But make sure you delete cache from the var folder after making the changes

Comment: thanks for all of you really :) just one question @Hit's my magento version is 2.2.4 so what's the appropriate patch to downold and thanks again

Comment: After magento 2 release they have removed patch concept to install manually, you can just run **composer update** from root folder that's it. or update version check [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/217348/55928)

Comment: so no way to scan my application? i feel not assured to update from 2.2.4 to 2.2.6 because i am affraid that it will damage the appalication somehow becuase i am in validation period of my project on the server of test :D  so what do you advise me ? and didi you tried that and thanks again

Comment: You can use Two-Factor Authentication (2FA)

Comment: what is this please and thanks for your replay